# command line input for J

Tags: input, j

I am trying to read command line input following this link (http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/hashbang.htm)

```
0".>,.2}.ARGV
```

I can understand that **2}.ARGV** drops the "jconsole" and the program name part.

**0".** turns string into numbers

why do we need **,.**

which seems to add an extra rank to the input parameters unnecessarily, in case

```
'a b c d' =: 0".>,.2}.ARGV
 $a
 1
```

Why not just

```
'a b c d' =: 0".> 2}.ARGV
$a
```

Another cautionary note:

```
'a' =: 0".> 2}.ARGV
$a
1
```

So if you only have one argument passed in, `'a'` becomes a list with rank 1, rather than one element of the input list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that without the `,.`, the result is not always a list of "number"ed (`".`) items, one for each argument. Ravelling guarantees that `0".` will apply to each argument separately.

For example, if your ARGV is a list of characters:

```
]in =: 2 }. ARGV
┌─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│3│4│
└─┴─┴─┴─┘
> ,. in
1
2
3
4
```

but

```
> in
1234
```

so

```
0". > ,. in
1 2 3 4
```

but

```
0". > in
1234
```

Other ways to apply `0".` to each argument separately include `(0". >)"0 in` and `> 0". &.> in`. From those three, the one using the ravel is the most efficient.

Comment: just like to point out, if **]in=: 11;2;3;4** then **> in** seems to be able to pad the numbers with spacing correctly

Comment: @ZheHu, yes, in most cases the two are almost equivalent. It's the special cases that produce wrong results when `,.` is missing.